# In case of Video segment sidx box be included with only I-Frame?

Tags: mp4, fmp4

In case of Video segment sidx box be included with only I-Frame?
In case of dash segment Box structure is below
`styp sidx moof mdat`
or
`styp moof mdat`

In case of Audio we can make every segment with sidx but,
In case of Video we only make sidx box when I-Frame is Coming (I think that If B or P-frame
Coming, we should not make sidx.)
Is it right or not ??